# Android: Get the id of the Radio Group of the Radio button selected

Tags: android

I have 2 `Radio Groups`. Each one has 2 `Radio buttons`. How can I get the `id` of the `radio group` of the `radio button` selected?

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnCheckedChangeListener()` to your `RadioGroup` and get the selected `RadioGroup` `ID` from method `onCheckedChanged()`.

**Try this:**

```
int selectedRadioGroupId = 0;

// Group 1
radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {

            selectedRadioGroupId = radioGroup.getId();

            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.button1:

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton1.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.button2:

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton2.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }
        }
    });

// Group 2
radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {

            selectedRadioGroupId = radioGroup.getId();

            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.button3:

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton3.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.button4:

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton4.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @porthfind What is the current status of your issue. Is it working now?